# Django filter timestamp__range

Tags: python, django

I want to apply a range filter on a timestamp field, based on query parameters `start` and `end`.
My view looks like this:

```
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView
from rest_framework.generics import RetrieveAPIView
from .models import HourlyTick
from .serializer import HourlyTickSerializer

# Create your views here.

class HourlyTickList(ListAPIView):
    def get(self, request):
        start = request.GET.get('start', None)
        end = request.GET.get('end', None)
        return HourlyTick.objects.filter(timestamp__range(start, end))

class HourlyTickDetail(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = HourlyTick.objects.all()
    serializer_class = HourlyTickSerializer
```

Model:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class HourlyTick(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    symbol = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    open = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    high = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    low = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    close = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    trades = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    volume = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    vwap = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'xbtusd_hourly'
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path, re_path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    re_path('hourlyticks', views.HourlyTickList.as_view())
]
```

The error I receive is:

> name 'timestamp__range' is not defined

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing an equal sign. It should be:

```
return HourlyTick.objects.filter(timestamp__range=(start, end))
```

You will also need to convert your datetime strings to datetime objects.

Comment: Omg indeed. Why convert? It is in the format of a datetime field?